# Xcode: Whole folder structure in Finder is messed up

Tags: xcode, rename

I've finished my app and wanted to clean up code, folder etc. My problem is probably that I've started the app project with a different name and renamed it during development. But only in Xcode. Now I some folder structure like

```
ProjectName1->some files
ProjectName1->ProjectName1->some files
ProjectName1->ProjectName2->some files
```

Where ProjectName1 is of course the first name. I've tried to rearrange the folder structure in Finder (and delete some wrong ones, move images to their own folders etc.) and link all files in XCode thereafter to their respective folders. Furthermore I've changed my build settings where my old project name was still included. But somehow my app doesn't compile anymore with multiple errors about files not found and with this warning:

```
Warning: The Copy Bundle Resources build phase contains this target's Info.plist file 'NetIncome-Info.plist'.
```

No idea what that means. What did I do wrong? Is this even possible to rearrange the folder structure and names so late in a project? I just wanted some structure in my folders and not all files in one folder and I want to remove the old project name completely...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your project settings under

Build Phases > Copy Bundle Resources

Remove your **NetIncome-Info.plist** file.

Comment: So you don't need this file for the build but you should have it in the project?

Comment: @MichiZH You do need it, but not in the `Resources` folder. It will be automatically copied to the `Contents` folder.

Answer (score 3):

The error means: don't include your Info.plist file in your target. It is referenced in the build settings and shouldn't be copied.

so again: to fix: don't make the file part of the target.